# Problems while trying to select rows based on a restriction?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the below dataframe:

```
Col A           Col B 
orange          yes         
apple           no
watermelon      yes
peas            yes
carrot          yes
carrot          no
apple           no
orange          yes         
watermelon      no
carrot          yes
apple           no
peas            no
```

How can I select 4 different elements from `Col A` with the restriction that `Col B` must have 2 `True` and 2 `False` interleaved values, for example, a valid extraction looks like this:

```
Col A           Col B 
orange          yes         
apple           no
carrot          yes
watermelon      no
```

I tried to use the query API call:

```
a = a_df.query("Col B == True")[:4]
b = a_df.query("Col B == False")[:4]

merged = pd.concat([a, b], axis=0).drop_duplicates(subset=['Col B'])
```

However, I am only getting two values instead of the requiered four. Any idea of how to get the above filtering with pandas?

From @sammywemmy answer I tried:

```
df['X'] = np.where(df['Col B']=='yes', True, False)
forward = df['X'].gt(df['X'].shift(-1))
backward = df['X'].lt(df['X'].shift(-1))
filters = df.index[forward].union(df.index[backward])


df.loc[filters].drop_duplicates(subset=['Col B'])
```

However, it doesnt work because I only get a dtaframe with two rows.

Comment: `"using the query API"` <- do you mean the answer must use `df.query()`?

Comment: Not necesarly, but I am just curious if that's possible because I found that functionality useful @tdy

Comment: Is order significant? (i.e. these are ***permutations***, not (set) combinations?) Hence we are to take it that `carrot True` in both line 4 and line 9, `orange True` in lines 1 and 7, must all be kept as being distinct. And the order of the input dataframe is significant, i.e. we can't just sort and uniquify(/drop duplicates) on both `['Col A', 'Col B']`?

Comment: No the order does not matter. The only thing that matters is to get different items in Col A, with the restriction that they should be True, and false @smci

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong because it won't consider both possibilities carrot True and carrot False, it just takes the first carrot row which is carrot True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

Get indices where True is immediately followed by False:

```
df['Col C'] = df['Col B'].map({"yes":True, "no":False})
forward = df['Col C'].gt(df['Col C'].shift(-1))
backward = df['Col C'].lt(df['Col C'].shift(-1))
filters = df.index[forward].union(df.index[backward])
```

Filter for those indices and drop the duplicates:

```
    df.loc[filters].drop_duplicates()
        Col A Col B  Col C
0      orange   yes   True
1       apple    no  False
4      carrot   yes   True
8  watermelon    no  False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, what if Col B are not booleans, they are strings?

Comment: we'll have to find a way to convert to booleans. share a question, coupled with what you have tried, and let the community help you.

Comment: I can create an additional column with those values, however, I am not sure if that's the cleanest way `df['X'] = np.where(df['Col B']=='str1', True, False)
`

Comment: No this is wrong, it exclude legit candidates containing `carrot False`. You can only drop genuine duplicate rows where *both* Col A and B are identical, and those rows are consecutive. Anything else could legitimately be a candidate.

Comment: Yes, by using an additional column it is not working anymore

Comment: kindly add the additional column to your original question

Comment: Edited the answer. Let me know if it fits your use case. You can always drop column C since it is not part of the original question. Also, the unique columns you are interested in are from column A, not B. the true/false filters would keep relevant rows, allowing you to filter out duplicates from column A. all said, you know your data best, so you'll know the best way to go about it